# Binding to Loopback Adapter in Windows 2008 Server

Tags: c++, networking, network-programming, windows-server-2008

For testing purposes, I'm trying to run a number of client applications connecting to a server all on the same host machine.

The host machine is running Windows 2008 Server Standard 32-bit with Service Pack 2.

On my XP development machine I installed the [Microsoft Loopback Adapter](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/839013) in order to run multiple clients connecting from separate IP addresses. My LAN network is 192.168.1.xxx and so I chose 192.168.5.xxx for the loopback adapter addresses.

On my development machine, everything works fine and I am able to see the client applications binding to the loopback adapter using [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437).

When I try and run the same setup on the Windows 2008 server with the same settings, the client applications are unable to bind to the loopback adapter addresses. There is no activity in TCPView and so I believe there's possibly some configuration setting I'm missing in setting up the loopback adapter.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved. I was specifying that the client connect to 127.0.0.1 but when I asked it to connect to a 192.168.5.x address it worked. The server was bound to 0.0.0.0 which suggests that it should still have been bound to 127.0.0.1 anyway but it just didn't seem to work!

Comment: This may have been a firewall issue, BTW.

Comment: @Ben: Firewall is turned off.